# Mysql. After deleting row i can not set trigger to automatic update saldo

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql database. I have a table with running balance (saldo). When i delete 1 row. Running balance (saldo) under a row i jut deleted, is not update. Like this picture below.
[running balance error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oFKE.jpg)

So I recalculate running balance (saldo) with this code in sql:

```
set @Balance := 0;
update kastunai
set saldo = (@Balance := @Balance + kredit - debet) order by no_urut
```

This work fine in sql. But i want to put it into "automatic trigger after delete row" so i do not have to run it manually every time i deleted a row to update running balance (saldo). Or maybe some php code to help with.

I try trigger after delete but error message appear:

*"The following query has failed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test` AFTER DELETE ON `kastunai` 
FOR EACH ROW 
set @Balance := 0 
update kastunai a set a.saldo = (@Balance := @Balance + 
    a.kredit - a.debet) 
    order by a.no_urut
```

`MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'update kastunai a set a.saldo = (@Balance := @Balance + a.kredit - a.debet) ord' at line 2"`*

Comment: Don't store derived data

Comment: I think you missed semicolon in `set @Balance := 0`

Comment: There are multiple statements in your trigger so you must wrap them in a begin...end block, and the statements must be terminated and you will need to set delimiters see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Your update looks dangerously lacking a where statement and in a delete trigger I would expect to see reference to OLD. values. And I don't think your logic is correct I suspect you have to recalculate running balance from a start point adjusting for every transaction which may be a bit heavy,

Comment: P. Salmon.what p1 mean?..yes...i had to recalculate from beginning. Please help me if you know  better way / code to handle that update.

Comment: Tamil : I place that semicolon but not working. still error.

Comment: Strawberry...I'm sorry if i make some mistake...but what you mean by derived data?